# How to change request url in wsgi middleware

Tags: python, http-post, wsgi

I got a request url in WSGI middleware when someone sent the POST request. I need to change the url in middleware before it pass to the application. Then, I did something like that:

```
class myfunction(wsgi.middleware):
  def process_request(self, req):
    req.url = 'http://XXXX'
```

Actually I just want to add some parameters in the request url.

But unfortunately it was not working and I got an error in webob/request.py:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/webob/request.py", line 1387, in __setattr__
object.__setattr__(self, attr, value)
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I just wonder whether I will never change the POST request url because it is a rule. If possible, kindly let me know how to change it.